# Google Plus login button frame type kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am able to login properly but unable to change button size, here is my code. How can I change GPPSignInButton height and width?

```
GPPSignInButton *signInButton11 = [[GPPSignInButton alloc] init];
[signInButton11 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[signInButton11 setStyle:kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide];
[signInButton11 setColorScheme:kGPPSignInButtonColorSchemeDark];
[signInButton11 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"g_plus_icone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //  custom image

CGRect frame = signInButton11.frame;
frame.origin.x =signInButton.frame.origin.x+signInButton.frame.size.width+10;
frame.origin.y = signInButton.frame.origin.y;
signInButton11.frame = frame;

[self.view addSubview:signInButton11];
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;

signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.scopes = @[@"profile"];
signIn.delegate = self;
```

Comment: change the button style signInButton11.style = kGPPSignInButtonStyleStandard; and try once

Comment: I tried this also, not working :-(